# Moment.js YYYY-M-DD Invalid IN IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Simple question.  Why is value false and value2 true?  Just for fun, value 3 does work.
After the first three comments and some testing I have been forced to change my question.

```
var value = "1970-5-29";
var value2 = "1970-05-29";
var value3 = "1970/5/29";

alert(moment(value).isValid());
alert(moment(value2).isValid());
alert(moment(value3).isValid());
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYUfG/16/)

Is there some bug in moment.js that I am missing?  Or is YYYY-M-DD not accepted universally?

Comment: Me too, they all return true

Comment: That fiddle alerts true three times, although you don't have Moment.JS running in the fiddle so I'm not exactly sure what it is that it's evaulating.

Comment: Does that mean it could be a browser or system setting?

Comment: See my answer. There's a specific list of formats Moment.js will read, and single digit month/double digit year is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the moment.js documentation, here's the list of valid formats:

```
The following ISO-8601 formats are supported across all browsers.

"2013-02-08"
"2013-02-08T09"
"2013-02-08 09"
"2013-02-08T09:30"
"2013-02-08 09:30"
"2013-02-08T09:30:26"
"2013-02-08 09:30:26"
"2013-02-08T09:30:26.123"
"2013-02-08 09:30:26.123"
"2013-02-08T09:30:26 Z"
"2013-02-08 09:30:26 Z"
"2013-W06-5"
"2013-W06-5T09"
"2013-W06-5 09"
"2013-W06-5T09:30"
"2013-W06-5 09:30"
"2013-W06-5T09:30:26"
"2013-W06-5 09:30:26"
"2013-W06-5T09:30:26.123"
"2013-W06-5 09:30:26.123"
"2013-W06-5T09:30:26 Z"
"2013-W06-5 09:30:26 Z"
"2013-039"
"2013-039T09"
"2013-039 09"
"2013-039T09:30"
"2013-039 09:30"
"2013-039T09:30:26"
"2013-039 09:30:26"
"2013-039T09:30:26.123"
"2013-039 09:30:26.123"
"2013-039T09:30:26 Z"
"2013-039 09:30:26 Z"

If a string does not match any of the above formats and is not able to be parsed with Date.parse, moment#isValid will return false.
```

So since it isn't in that list, if it won't parse by date.Parse(), it's not going to show as valid.

Comment: So just to go off what you have posted.  YYYY-M-DD is not a ISO-8601 format. Therefore, some browsers might not support it.  In this particular case, IE does not support it and Chrome does?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that Date.Parse() works fine on that value in Chrome. But maybe it doesn't in other browsers? But there's your answer -- moment.js will take any format off that list and anything that date.parse will work on. I'm running OS X so I can't debug in IE for you, but I'd suspect that it's a date.parse() implementation issue.